# Select with one or more conditions using PDO OOP

Tags: php, pdo

I have the method below to select from database with one or more conditions. But it doesn't get any results, i put a `var_dump($this)` before `return $this;` at method `query` and it shows:

```
array(2) {
    ["program"]=> string(10) "INFANTOZOO"
    ["active"]=> string(4) "não"
}
array(2) {
    ["program"]=> string(10) "INFANTOZOO"
    ["active"]=> string(4) "não"
}
object(DB)#3 (5) {
    ["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { }
    ["_query":"DB":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) {
        ["queryString"]=> string(53) "SELECT * FROM test WHERE program = ? AND active = ?"
    }
    ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false)
    ["_results":"DB":private]=> array(0) { }
    ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(0)
}
```

I don't have any idea what i'm missing here, can somebody help me? Sorry if is a dumb question, i'm new at PDO OOP, but i'm really freaking out with this! Thank you very much!

```
public function select($table, $fields){
    $set = '';
    $x = 1;
    foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
        $set .= "{$name} = ?";
        if ($x < count($fields)) {
            $set .= ' AND ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$set}";
    if (!DB::query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return $this;
    }
    return false;
}
```

-

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if (count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++; 
                var_dump($params);
            }
        } 


        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();

        } else{
            print_r($this->_query->errorInfo());
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }
    var_dump($this);
    return $this;


}
```

This is how i'm calling the method:

```
$est = DB::getInstance()->select('test', array('program' => 'INFANTOZOO', 'active' => 'não'));
```

Comment: Does the query `SELECT * FROM test WHERE program = 'INFANTOZOO' AND active = 'não'` works if you run directly into your database?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Yep, it runs perfectly!

Comment: And fetch how many lines? It seems that isn't any error here. Are you sure you're running in the same database?

Comment: It fetch two lines. Yep, it's the same db! I'm calling the method like this `$est = DB::getInstance()->select('test', array('program' => 'INFANTOZOO', 'active' => 'não'));` Maybe there is something worng here, the `getInstance` is to instance a new DB class

Comment: Don't make singletons, don't use wildcard in your selects, and don't make database wrapper classes.